# Give property names/values with @Component

Tags: java, spring, components, autowired

Please deal with this basic question.

I used to use @Autowired annotation where properties (class variables) can be given a value using key/value format for that class.

```
<bean id="class" class="a.b.c.Class" lazy-init="true">
        <property name="var1" value="${var1}" />
</bean>
```

I changed Class to a @Component with component scan option which doesn't require its autowiring. How can I add property variables now?

Also, I don't want to get into trouble while writing Junits.

Thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're thinking of properties from a properties file, check out [`@PropertySource`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/PropertySource.html) and the [`@Value`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Value.html) annotation.

```
@Component
@PropertySource("classpath:myProps.properties")
public class MyComponent {

    @Value("${some.property}")
    private String valueFromProperty;

    // You can also use environment
    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    public void someMethod() {
        String prop = env.getProperty("some.property");
        MyBean bean = new MyBean();
        bean.setProp(prop);
        return bean;
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean? If you're talking about unit tests, I prefer not to use Spring to resolve my dependencies, and just "hand wire" stuff. But if you're using the Spring test runners and the correct context configuration it should work.

Comment: Sorry for deleting the comment. 

I meant, can we directly inject Value annotation as we do for Autowired ones?

Comment: `@Value` should be injected when the bean is created, so I assume the answer is yes.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Spring's @Value annotation in the reference ([Chapter 4. IoC container](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html)).

The properties should be loaded:

```
<beans>
   <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:/com/acme/your.properties"/>
</beans>
```